# tensorflow facemesh delay in tracking landmark points

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using face-mesh for one of ma POC the landmarks and detection are absolutely superb.

But what i found is while moving the face the tracking is little delayed ? is there any configuration available to sort this out ? when i move quickly it taking even more time to detect landmarks on right place. i tried with both wasm and webgl. perfomance wise absolutely no problem here but. tracking is delaying which is not giving the expected result.

is anything i'm missing to get this right ? any help on this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A small delay is to be expected as inference will probably be tens of milliseconds at least from my experience.

What FPS are you getting? It will very much depend on your hardware of course. As WASM improves hopefully things will get faster too for free on CPU.

On my machine (Desktop running GTX 1070) I get around 50 FPS in WebGL and 25 FPS with just the i7 CPU via WASM only.

From what you have said I do not think you have missed anything. If you could post a screen recording of the situation and live demo eg on CodePen or Glitch, that would could help me compare with what I am seeing to confirm this.

Comment: i am fine the minor delay in desktops or laptop..there is a delay but its okey.. but in mobile phones it little more i am using OnePlus6 which is having a pretty good hardware but there FPS is very less.

i am getting similar FPS as you mentioned. webgl is giving better FPS but in iphone it work with only wasm.

here is a screen record - 
https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-3618a3686ac7.gif

Comment: https://dev.kiksar.com/ezgif-3-3618a3686ac7.gif previous one is temporary link here the permanent one

Comment: Interesting on my Pixel 2XL from a few years ago I get about 13 FPS and that laggyness is much less than the gif you shared - it seems usable on Pixel 2XL. What version of iPhone are you using to test?

Comment: PS try changing maxFaces to 1 - then it should be faster too as it will stop searching faster for faces. See documentation https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/facemesh

facemesh.load(
  {
    maxFaces: 1
  }
);

Comment: this one is running with maxFaces 1

Comment: I am out of ideas lol. In that case the only difference is the hardware we are running on so this may be a hardware limitation in this case but hopefully will get faster with time as improvements to WASM etc come out too.

Comment: hopeing for the best :) thanks for your response though.

Comment: Any improvements on this ?? the FPS is dead slow in almost all android devices.. except oneplus7,google pixel, and samsung galaxy s20. not able to take a decision to use this or not.. :(

Comment: Can you list the devices it is specifically slow on you have tested?

Comment: Almost all android devices.. except google pixel oneplus7 and above... i tested and getting very less FPS in one plus 5T, few huawei  devices.. almost bunch of MI devices and vivo/oppo devices..so far i found its giving 18-20 fps in iphone and google pixel and one plus 7.. if its support only such devices it wont help us :(

Comment: It may be a requirement to have a recent generation mobile phone to do the ML in this case. One plus 5T is pretty old now and ML only started taking off in the last few years - with the newer phones having better chips for such mathematics etc. To get better performance than this you may have to create your own model that is simpler eg like https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/blazeface - does that work faster for you?